# How to create share options like on Android in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, share

I need to show an option to share some details like on Android using Swift.
How do I show the screen with a list of applications to share?
Please see the below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: [Add sharing to your Swift app via UIActivityViewController](https://www.codingexplorer.com/sharing-swift-app-uiactivityviewcontroller/), [How to share content with UIActivityViewController](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-share-content-with-uiactivityviewcontroller), [UIActivityViewController by example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example), [How To Share Content With UIActivityViewController](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2017/08/how-to-share-content-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try somethings like this:

```
private func shareWhatYouWant() {

    //pop invite view
    var textToShare = "Your message"
    if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "Yourwebsite.com") {
        let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite] as [Any]
        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        //New Excluded Activities Code

        activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = {
            activity, sucess, items, error in
            if !sucess {
                print("cancelled")
                return
            }
            if activity == UIActivityType.postToFacebook {
                print("share on facebook")
            }
            if activity == UIActivityType.postToTwitter {
                print("share on twitter")
            }
            if activity == UIActivityType.message {
                print("share on message")
            }
            if activity == UIActivityType.addToReadingList {
                print("air drop select")
            }
        }

        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as? UIView
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```